# What is the difference between Errors , Dropped , Overruns , Frame and Carrier

Tags: linux, ifconfig

What is the difference between `Errors` , `Dropped` , `Overruns` ,  `Frame` and  `Carrier` in the `Ifconfig` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Linux `ifconfig` gets the raw data statistics from `/proc/net/dev`.

The values there (with ifconfig destination in brackets added) are described by an article [Exploring the /proc/net/ Directory](http://www.onlamp.com/pub/a/linux/2000/11/16/LinuxAdmin.html) as:

- errs (Errors): The total number of transmit or receive errors
  detected by the device driver.
- drop (Dropped): The total number of packets dropped by the device
  driver.
- fifo (Overruns): The number of FIFO buffer errors.
- frame (Frame): The number of packet framing errors.
- carrier (Carrier): The number of carrier losses detected by the
  device driver.